# Отправка данных в MySQL базу, с помощью Python

Tags: python

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config

def insert_login(username, password):
    query = "INSERT INTO login(username,password) " 
    "VALUES(%s,%s)"
    args = (username, password)

    try:
        db_config = read_db_config()
        conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, args)

        if cursor.lastrowid:
            print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
        else:
            print('last insert id not found')

            conn.commit()
    except Error as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

def main():
   insert_login('User','Passw')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

У меня есть дополнительные файлы для подключения к БД, но проблема только в этом, когда я запускаю код, мне выводится ошибка:

```
Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Что нужно исправить или добавить, чтобы загрузить данные?

Comment: Полагаю, переменную `query` записать правильно?

Comment: правильно? я не могу просто что именно

Comment: `query = "INSERT INTO login(username,password)" + " VALUES(%s,%s)"`

Comment: а всё , спасибо! разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Редко пользуюсь MySQL, но вот мой темплейтик, на случай если забуду

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
import socket
# import getpass
# getpass.getuser()
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

def query_with_fetchone():
   try:
       conn = MySQLConnection(host='192.168.0.000', user='Name', password='*****', database='database_NAME')

       cursor = conn.cursor()

       try:
           cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE img_weights(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, weights FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
       except:
           pass



       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO img_weights (weights) VALUES(301.234)")
       conn.commit()


       cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM img_weights")
       row = cursor.fetchone()


       while row is not None:
           print(row)
           row = cursor.fetchone()

       conn.commit()

   except Error as e:
       print(e)

   finally:
       cursor.close()
       conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   query_with_fetchone()
```